# Is there a HTTP Completion Option for a post request in System.Net.Http?

Tags: c#, httprequest

I want to send a post request but to speed things up not to download the entire page, just the head (or some smaller section of the content). I know there is a way you can do this with get requests but I need to do this with a post request.
I am programming with c# and System.Net.Http. However, I am willing to use another library if its necessary.

Here is how the get request can only download headers:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
var getTask = client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
```

And here is my current code:

```
var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: If the api supports it, you can [get a range of bytes from the response with the Accept-Range header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just change `HttpMethod.Get` to `HttpMethod.Post` in your first sample, and assign to `request.Content`:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url)
{
    Content = content,
};
var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
```

Of course, calling `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` negates the point of using `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head, "your url");
 httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
```

Comment: The asker explicitely wants a POST request, not a HEAD request.